# Сбрасываются значения всех элементов на странице, при отправке с помощью post

Tags: php, jquery

Есть простейшая форма, в которой при выборе определенной опции из селекта - формируются инпуты со значениями из БД,но проблема в том, что после выбора селекта,как будто-то бы,обновляется страница и все значения сбрасываются, как такой вопрос можно решить?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".material" ).change(function() {
var material_v = this.value;
      $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'material.php',
      data: { material_v:material_v },
      success: function(data){
        $('#wrap').html(data);
        return false;
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

[image: Вот первый скриншот]
----------------------------------------[image: После выбора селекта]

Comment: вы думаете, что проблема в Аякс запросе?! Что у вас лежит в id="wrap", в который вы отправляете ответ от сервера?

Comment: весь контент, но если я сделаю условный див result,то он тупо туда весь код продублирует и будет 2 формы.

Comment: ну если вы весь контент меняете, то он весь и меняется - как при перезагрузке. Меняйте либо часть контента или добавляйте полученные данные в ответ сервера (во втором случае нет смысла в аяксе, т.к. всё равно обновляются все данные)